I face problem with fl chart leftTitleWidgets
I need 10 rows to show my Data (0, 2, 2.25, ...... 4)on leftTitleWidgets. But the values of the FlSpot are maximal 4. So data is along with 2.75 only when its value is 4. How can I solve this problem?
This is what I get...

The thing I want...

Here is my code
import 'package:diu_result/controller/semester_result_controller.dart';
import 'package:diu_result/model/semester_cgpa_model.dart';
import 'package:fl_chart/fl_chart.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

import '../../../utils/const/app_color.dart';

class LineChartSample2 extends StatefulWidget {
  const LineChartSample2({super.key});

  @override
  State<LineChartSample2> createState() => _LineChartSample2State();
}

class _LineChartSample2State extends State<LineChartSample2> {
  final controller = Get.find<SemesterResultController>();

  List<Color> gradientColors = [
    AppColors.contentColorCyan,
    AppColors.contentColorBlue,
  ];

  bool showAvg = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        AspectRatio(
          aspectRatio: .8,
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
              right: 0,
              left: 0,
              top: 24,
              bottom: 20,
            ),
            child: LineChart(
              showAvg ? avgData() : mainData(),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          width: 60,
          height: 34,
          child: TextButton(
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                showAvg = !showAvg;
              });
            },
            child: Text(
              'avg',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 12,
                color: showAvg ? Colors.white.withOpacity(0.5) : Colors.white,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget bottomTitleWidgets(double value, TitleMeta meta) {
    const style = TextStyle(
      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
      fontSize: 10,
    );

    // Convert the double value to an int for comparison
    int index = value.toInt() - 1;

    // Initialize a variable to hold the widget
    Widget text;

    // Check if the index is within the bounds of the semesterCgpaList
    if (index >= 0 && index < controller.semesterNameCg.length) {
      // Get the corresponding SemesterCgpaModel
      SemesterCgpaModel semesterCgpa = controller.semesterNameCg[index];

      // Create the text widget with the semester name and year
      text = Text(
        '${semesterCgpa.semesterName}\n${semesterCgpa.semesterYear}',
        style: style,
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      );
    } else {
      text = const Text('', style: style);
    }

    return SideTitleWidget(
      axisSide: meta.axisSide,
      child: text,
    );
  }

  Widget leftTitleWidgets(double value, TitleMeta meta) {
    const style = TextStyle(
      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
      fontSize: 12,
    );

    String text;
    switch (value) {
      case 0:
        text = '0.0';
        break;
      case 1:
        text = '2.0';
        break;
      case 2:
        text = '2.25';
        break;
      case 3:
        text = '2.5';
        break;
      case 4:
        text = '2.75';
        break;
      case 5:
        text = '3.0';
        break;
      case 6:
        text = '3.25';
        break;
      case 7:
        text = '3.5';
        break;
      case 8:
        text = '3.75';
        break;
      case 9:
        text = '4.0';
        break;
      default:
        return Container();
    }

    return Text(text, style: style, textAlign: TextAlign.left);
  }

  LineChartData mainData() {
    return LineChartData(
      gridData: FlGridData(
        show: true,
        drawVerticalLine: false,
        horizontalInterval: 1,
        verticalInterval: 1,
        getDrawingHorizontalLine: (value) {
          return const FlLine(
            color: AppColors.mainGridLineColor,
            strokeWidth: 1,
          );
        },
      ),
      titlesData: FlTitlesData(
        show: true,
        rightTitles: const AxisTitles(
          sideTitles: SideTitles(showTitles: false),
        ),
        topTitles: const AxisTitles(
          sideTitles: SideTitles(showTitles: false),
        ),
        bottomTitles: AxisTitles(
          sideTitles: SideTitles(
            showTitles: true,
            reservedSize: 40,
            interval: 1,
            getTitlesWidget: bottomTitleWidgets,
          ),
        ),
        leftTitles: AxisTitles(
          sideTitles: SideTitles(
            showTitles: true,
            interval: 1,
            getTitlesWidget: leftTitleWidgets,
            reservedSize: 32,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      borderData: FlBorderData(
        show: false,
        border: Border.all(color: const Color(0xff37434d)),
      ),
      minX: .8,
      maxX: controller.semesterNameCg.length.toDouble() + 1,
      minY: 0,
      maxY: 10,
      lineBarsData: [
        LineChartBarData(
          spots: List.generate(
            controller.semesterNameCg.length,
            (index) {
              final cgpa = controller.semesterNameCg[index].cgpa;
              return FlSpot(index.toDouble() + 1, cgpa);
            },
          ),
          isCurved: true,
          gradient: LinearGradient(colors: gradientColors),
          barWidth: 3,
          isStrokeCapRound: true,
          dotData: const FlDotData(show: true),
          belowBarData: BarAreaData(
            show: true,
            gradient: LinearGradient(
              colors: gradientColors
                  .map((color) => color.withOpacity(0.3))
                  .toList(),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  LineChartData avgData() {
    return LineChartData(
      lineTouchData: const LineTouchData(enabled: false),
      gridData: FlGridData(
        show: true,
        drawHorizontalLine: true,
        verticalInterval: 1,
        horizontalInterval: 1,
        getDrawingVerticalLine: (value) {
          return const FlLine(
            color: Color(0xff37434d),
            strokeWidth: 0,
          );
        },
        getDrawingHorizontalLine: (value) {
          return const FlLine(
            color: Color(0xff37434d),
            strokeWidth: 1,
          );
        },
      ),
      titlesData: FlTitlesData(
        show: true,
        bottomTitles: AxisTitles(
          sideTitles: SideTitles(
            showTitles: true,
            reservedSize: 30,
            getTitlesWidget: bottomTitleWidgets,
            interval: 1,
          ),
        ),
        leftTitles: AxisTitles(
          sideTitles: SideTitles(
            showTitles: true,
            getTitlesWidget: leftTitleWidgets,
            reservedSize: 32,
            interval: 1,
          ),
        ),
        topTitles: const AxisTitles(
          sideTitles: SideTitles(showTitles: false),
        ),
        rightTitles: const AxisTitles(
          sideTitles: SideTitles(showTitles: false),
        ),
      ),
      borderData: FlBorderData(
        show: true,
        border: Border.all(color: const Color(0xff37434d)),
      ),
      minX: 0,
      maxX: 10,
      minY: 0,
      maxY: 11,
      lineBarsData: [
        LineChartBarData(
          spots: const [
            FlSpot(0, 3.44),
            FlSpot(2.6, 3.44),
            FlSpot(4.9, 3.44),
            FlSpot(6.8, 3.44),
            FlSpot(8, 3.44),
            FlSpot(9.5, 3.44),
            FlSpot(11, 3.44),
          ],
          isCurved: true,
          gradient: LinearGradient(
            colors: [
              ColorTween(begin: gradientColors[0], end: gradientColors[1])
                  .lerp(0.2)!,
              ColorTween(begin: gradientColors[0], end: gradientColors[1])
                  .lerp(0.2)!,
            ],
          ),
          barWidth: 5,
          isStrokeCapRound: true,
          dotData: const FlDotData(show: false),
          belowBarData: BarAreaData(
            show: true,
            gradient: LinearGradient(
              colors: [
                ColorTween(begin: gradientColors[0], end: gradientColors[1])
                    .lerp(0.2)!
                    .withOpacity(0.1),
                ColorTween(begin: gradientColors[0], end: gradientColors[1])
                    .lerp(0.2)!
                    .withOpacity(0.1),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}


Can you try increasing value on FlSpot's Y axis. seems your are using different value based inside  leftTitleWidgets

if i increase the value i get different result which i don't want.
Here is a video demo.....
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1gNhDHHUlsfwWwBrgBQrn8bZFJDsoK7pC?usp=sharing

now you can adjust the the switch to render the leftTitleWidgets

brother, can you give me some more details?
